# SnowFlake Query returns NULL on some fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Have this ODBC connection to retrieve data from Snowflake to my Laravel 5.8 application,
and It currently working fine, the problem is when I running a simple SELECT STATEMENT all that data that is type VARCHAR(16777216) its coming NULL.

I don't have any idea why this is hapenning, but when I connect this snowflake through my Dbeaver, It works fine.
I'm very confused about snowflake documentation, and already tried to cast the return to UTF-8 but It didnt work.

This is a dump from my data coming through this connection:

```
      ^ array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1634 ▼
    +"ID": "10958317"
    +"GLOBAL_PERSON_ID": "64880"
    +"INSTANCE_ID": "1"
    +"SOURCE_ID": null
    +"FIRST_NAME": null
    +"LAST_NAME": null
    +"AVATAR_URL": null
    +"BIRTH_DATE": null
    +"EMAIL": null
    +"POSTAL_CODE": null
    +"INSTITUTION_ROLE": null
    +"INSTITUTION_ROLE_SOURCE_CODE": null
    +"INSTITUTION_ROLE_SOURCE_DESC": null
    +"SYSTEM_ROLE": null
    +"SYSTEM_ROLE_SOURCE_CODE": null
    +"SYSTEM_ROLE_SOURCE_DESC": null
    +"AVAILABLE_IND": null
    +"ENABLED_IND": null
    +"STAGE": null
    +"ROW_INSERTED_TIME": null
    +"ROW_UPDATED_TIME": null
    +"ROW_DELETED_TIME": null
    +"CREATED_TIME": null
    +"MODIFIED_TIME": null
  }
]
```

This is the same QUERY but running in Snowflake app.
[image]

This is the data type of the table:
[image]

This is my Laravel code trying to get the same result:

```
    public static function testConnect()
{
    return DB::connection('snowflake')->select("
    SELECT * FROM CDM_LMS.PERSON
    WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Calebe'
    ");
}
```

```
    Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#1629 ▼
  +connection: Dbt\Odbc\Connection {#1624 ▼
    -keyFormat: "database.connections.odbc.grammar.%s"
    #pdo: Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection {#1631 ▼
      inTransaction: false
      attributes: {▼
        CASE: NATURAL
        ERRMODE: EXCEPTION
        PERSISTENT: false
        DRIVER_NAME: "odbc"
        ORACLE_NULLS: NATURAL
        CLIENT_VERSION: "ODBC-Win32"
        STATEMENT_CLASS: array:2 [▼
          0 => "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Statement"
          1 => []
        ]
        DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE: BOTH
      }
    }
    #readPdo: null
    #database: "BLACKBOARD_DATA_6CB6608FBA4442E7A3F2161F82A41E70"
```

Comment: not all data id is correct, so you must have a left join without corresponding values in the other tabls

Comment: Nop, all data coming from same table. And the most weird part is that If I verify the data type of this fields, ID (Wich return smth) and GLOBAL_PERSON_ID have the same type.

Comment: show us the table with data and query in sql and text form  to make a [mre]

Comment: I added some prints to the question

Comment: please no images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface. Its not a piece of code, its just a GUI screenshot. Can't copy n paste this here.

Comment: @user3532758 did not work, already tried this

Comment: ID in the dd array and the ID in the screenshot are different. by any chance do you have different databases, maybe for testing or some? deleted previous comment because looks like it isnt accurate.

Comment: I didnt not step WHERE clause to filter by name 'Calebe', it was just my first record of array. But yeah, already checked and its the same ID. I'll change that array to the current example

Comment: what happens for `select 'foo'::varchar`

Comment: did not work too! As i said, looks like the problem doesnt ocurr when the type is NUMBER(38,0)

Answer (score 0):

Done using another package to create ODBC connection.

https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-odbc

Didn't figure out what was the problem with the other package but, it works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and stumbled upon this Bug:

[selects on long varchar fields returns empty with PDO ODBC](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63949)

If the content allows, create the fields with VARCHAR maximum 255, this helped me.